# How to use tokens for my app with Cordova, C# and javascript in visual studio?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, cordova, token

I am trying to make an app in C# and javascript with cordova that will have the user log in, create a token, and add a timeout to that token. With every action that is to be executed the token needs to be checked for the timeout. And I want this timeout to be editable.

So right now I have tried following this guide:
http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article165

But I am not able to implement it, nor have I managed to succeed in using techniques like window.token(I read that this is only for Android? My App needs to be for all devices) etc...

Question:
Are there any other availabilties for token authentication besides the ones I have mentioned? Or is token authentication outdated and should be replaced by something entirely different?

Comment: Do you want to authenticate user in C# WebApi?

Comment: @ramhemasri I have an App in javascript with webservices in C#. When the user logs in for the first time i want to create a token with a timeout. Then after whenever the App calls the webservice I want the webservice to look at the token, and verify that it is a valid token/call, and that the time has not ran out.